# Reset viewcontroller on UINavigation Back

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

**TL;DR:**

*How can I fully recreate/reset a view controller that I'm navigating back to from the automatically placed UINavigationController back button?*

- OldVC <- CurrentVC
- Ensure OldVC is completely reset.

Hi guys,

I'm using UINavigation and the automatically generated back button. When a user presses the back button, I want the previous view controller in the navigation stack to be fully reinstantiated - similar to how you would create the view controller then push to it.

I've tried the following but have been unable to find a solution:

- on view will load of the target VC, `self.view.setNeedsDisplay()` - doesn't recreate
- manually dropping the old VC from the stack and inserting a fresh one in it's place
- dismissing the VC - when leaving the main VC to the new VC, calling `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`
   doesn't drop the old VC from the stack

I have a temporary solution in place now using the following code, however from a UX perspective it is not right, as it relies on a custom button and an illogical animation from the push that makes the user think they are going further into the app rather than coming out, the code is below and recreates the VC fully (as you can see from the instantiation).

```
private func goToStoryBoard(name: String) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(name)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

UPDATE

It looks like the issue is with the way I am creating custom components - I initialise them once like below, but by doing it this way they will not update:

```
  class HomeMenuButton: UIButton { 
           required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { 
              super.init(coder: aDecoder)                                
              self.setTitleColor(InterfaceColors.MainFont, forState: .Normal) 
              self.titleLabel?.font = InterfaceFonts.ButtonFont 
      } 
}
```

Comment: Why you want to reset?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon it's after an app wide UI color change, I need the VC reset to set the color change, I think it's the easiest way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make a whole new view controller. Just implement `viewWillAppear:` to completely initialize the view. This will work the same both when the view controller's view *initially* appears and when it appears because the pushed view controller is being popped to reveal it.

(If any situations later arise where you *don't* want to reinitialize the view on `viewWillAppear:`, just raise a Bool flag on those occasions.)

Comment: Ah part of the reason I need it completely re-initialised is my UIComponents are subclassed and instantiated with configuration, as opposed to putting configuration in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()`, so my UI elements refer to the subclassed versions - if you see what I mean?

Comment: No, I don't see how that's germane. The whole purpose of the view controller is to tell its view (and its view's subviews) what to display. You should just do that. If you feel you can't, there's a serious design issue somewhere and _that_ is what you should be turning your attention to.

Comment: Maybe your answer confused me - how do you mean implement `viewWillAppear:` do you mean place instantiation in there, or something else?

Comment: E.g. my buttons and other interface elements are created outside of `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()` in a file that contains elements like this `class HomeMenuButton: UIButton {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        self.setTitleColor(InterfaceColors.MainFont, forState: .Normal)
        self.titleLabel?.font = InterfaceFonts.ButtonFont
        
    }
}`

Comment: I don't care where they are _created_. Do I? I mean, they didn't go away, did they? So they don't need to be created again. Do they? If they do, explain why. Thx.